# Displaying YAML variable with EBR to appear on website

Tags: html, yaml, erb

I am working on a project where data is stored in a YAML file with different variables and they are displayed on a web page using ERB. I can't seem to display the "des" variable contents, but I know that the pic_caption class statement is being displayed on the website when I do inspect.

I have managed to get two different YAML variables (stats) displayed using ERB as shown here:

YAML

```
impact:
  stats:
     - title: Number of Research Groups committed
       number: 3
     - title: Number of team members
       number: 22
```

ERB

```
<% if project.impact.key? 'stats' %>
        <% if project.impact.stats%>
          <% project.impact.stats.each do |s| %>
            <article class="impact__stat">
              <span class="impact__stat__title"><%= s.title %></span>
              <span class="impact__stat__number"><%= s.number %></span>
            </article>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

On the website, the titles and numbers are showing up as text, which is the desired result.

This is the code I am working on:

YAML

```
photos:
  - url: project-photos/bus-1.jpg
  - des: "hi"
  - url: project-photos/bus-2.jpg
  - des: "o"
```

ERB

```
      <% if project.photos %>
        <% project.photos.each do |i| %>
          <figure>
            <%= image_tag i.url %>
          </figure>
          <span class="pic_caption"><%= i.des %></span>
        <% end %>
      <!-- </div> -->
      <% end %>
```

I want the des variable to show up on the website but nothing shows up when I try doing that ERB code

Comment: Please note that there is no such thing as a YAML variable. The only time the word variable is used in the [YAML specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) is in an example document. So it is definitely the case that you are confusing concepts, which could well be the cause of not being able to solve the issue. "des" is a key in a mapping that consists of a single key-value pair, which is the second entry in a four entry sequence, which in itself is the value for the key "photos". And that is the single key-value pair of the root level mapping of this YAML document.

Answer (score 2):

Your YAML is not what you think it is:

```
photos:
  - url: project-photos/bus-1.jpg
  - des: "hi"
  - url: project-photos/bus-2.jpg
  - des: "o"
```

The value of `photos` here is a sequence of mappings. The first mapping has a key `url` with a value; the second mapping has a key `des` with a value, and so on.

However, the code you show assumes that each item in the list actually has a `url` *and* a `des` key. For that to work, you need to put `url` and `des` in the same mapping, like this:

```
photos:
  - url: project-photos/bus-1.jpg
    des: "hi"
  - url: project-photos/bus-2.jpg
    des: "o"
```

Notice the missing `-`. A `-` starts a new list entry.